ODOO: Activity and chatter message has no icon displayed in notification/navbar
When using odoo's default apps, every time I send a message using chatter or creating activity, it display the app's icon in the notification.
But when I use a custom module (x_custom_module), it only shows the avatar.jpg for message notification and no icon for activities.

The server actions I've used are self.message_post() and env['mail.activity']. How can I configure this with Odoo online/Odoo studio? thank you.
